# Dynamic Banner Text based on Subdomain

Tags: php, customization, subdomains

I'm working on a site where each agent has their own subdomain. Each subdomain directs to the content on the main page, there is no difference in content. The only difference requested is a banner that changes based on the subdomain used. For example:
bob.example.com
Would direct to example.com with a banner at the top that says "Welcome to Agent Bob's Portal!"
I'm not very experienced with WordPress, but what I was aiming for was something like:

```php
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 if (strpos($url, "bob."))  {
           print "Welcome to Agent Bob's Portal!";
        }
} ?>
```

The problem is that I'm not quite sure where to put it. I've tried putting it in the `page.php` file, surrounded by a div that encapsulates the area I want the text in, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there something else you would recommend trying?

Comment: I would take a look at a better function to get the subdomain - http://www.primitivetype.com/snippets/php_get_subdomain_from_host.php

Answer (score 0):

You can put you code in `functions.php` where you define the string, for example:

```
<?php   
function get_banner_text() {
  $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  if (strpos($url, "bob."))  {
    $banner_text = "Welcome to Agent Bob's Portal!";
  } else {
    $banner_text = "Default text here";
  }
  return $banner_text;
}
?>
```

Afterwards for example in `header.php` of your theme you could have like:

```
<div class="banner"><?php echo get_banner_text(); ?></div>
```